# Update Daily Counter Of Date From Specific Time

Tags: java, date, java-calendar

I have two dates with me say '2018-01-01'Start Date and '2018-01-31' End Date

I want to make my logic in a way that, each day my start date will increase until its reach 2018-02-28. Below is the code snippet I tried. How can this fix as Start Date should change on daily basis.

```
public class myclass {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        try {
            String dt = "2008-01-01";  // Start date
            String dt1 = "2008-01-31";  // End date
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // number of days to add
            dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());  //
            System.out.println(dt);
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

PS : This execution is Real Time, In scheduler which runs daily and check against the finale date from the given date. How many days remaining.

Thanks

Comment: You want the date to update in real time? I mean the program will actually run for months and each day `dt` will be updated? Another thing, what is the relevance of `dt1` (end date) to this program?

Comment: Hi, Yes Real Time, In scheduler which runs daily and check against the finale date from the given date. How many days remaining. dt1 can be ignore

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Why February if the Stop date is in January?

Comment: What kind of app? Console? Swing? Vaadin? Other web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `Runnable`

Define the work you need to done as a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html).

Then use a [`Scheduled ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to run this every minute or so, checking the current date against the target date. If the countdown has incremented, updated the display in the GUI. If not, do nothing, let the `Runnable` run again after another minute.

See the [Oracle Tutorial on Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();  // Use a single thread, as we need this to run sequentially, not in parallel.
ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay( r , 0L , 1L , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); // Pass the `Runnable`, an initial delay, a count to wait between runs, and the unit of time for those two other number arguments.
```

It would be more efficient to schedule a new `Runnable` each time, rather than auto-repeating, so as set the delay a calculated amount of time until the next midnight. This way the executor would sleep all day rather than running every minute. But that approach can go haywire if the user's clock updates to a significantly different current time or if the user's current default time zone changes (if you are depending on the default rather than setting one explicitly). Given how little this `Runnable` needs to do (just check current date & calc remaining days) there no practical reason to not just let it run every minute or two (however long is your minimum tolerance for fresh update to the user - a business policy of your app’s management).

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );  // Or ZoneId.systemDefault() to rely on the JVM’s current default time zone.
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## Example

Here is complete example. For more info, search Stack Overflow. The use of `ScheduledExecutorService` has been covered many times already.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class DailyCountdown implements Runnable {
    private LocalDate dueDate;
    private Long daysRemaining;

    public DailyCountdown ( LocalDate dueDate ) {
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }

    @Override
    public void run () {
        try {
            System.out.println( "DEBUG - Running the DailyCountdown::run method at " + Instant.now() );
            ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );  // Or ZoneId.systemDefault() to rely on the JVM’s current default time zone.
            LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
            Long count = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( today , this.dueDate );
            if ( Objects.isNull( this.daysRemaining ) ) {
                this.daysRemaining = ( count - 1 );
            }
            if ( this.daysRemaining.equals( count ) ) {
                // Do nothing.
            } else {
                // … Schedule on another thread for the GUI to update with the new number.
                this.daysRemaining = count;
            }
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            // Log this unexpected exception, and notify sysadmin.
            // Any uncaught exception reaching the scheduled executor service would have caused it to silently halt any further scheduling.
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        // Put this code where ever appropriate, when setting up your GUI after the app launches.
        Runnable r = new DailyCountdown( LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 15 ) );
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay( r , 0L , 1L , TimeUnit.MINUTES );

        // Be sure to gracefully shutdown the ScheduledExecutorService when your program is stopping. Otherwise, the executor may continue running indefinitely on the background thread.
        try {
            Thread.sleep( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis( 7 ) ); // Sleep 7 minutes to let the background thread do its thing.
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            System.out.println( "The `main` thread was woken early from sleep." );
        }
        ses.shutdown();
        System.out.println( "App is exiting at " + Instant.now() ) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8's time-API,you can achieve easily.

```
for (LocalDate date = startDate; date.isBefore(endDate); date = date.plusDays(1))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi This will run in one go, program is made to execute daily and increment the start date from provide interval.

Comment: For that you have to use schedular.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.util.Timer` class for this.

In below program I have taken a different approach. I'm NOT using a start date. I simply get the current date every day and check it against the target date (which is "2019-02-10" in this example). See if this works for your requirement.

(Use `FIVE_SECONDS_IN_MILLISECONDS` to test the program.)

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Scheduler {
  private static final long ONE_DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  private static final long FIVE_SECONDS_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000 * 5;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String dateString = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        System.out.println(dateString);
        if (dateString.equals("2019-02-10")) {
          System.out.println("Date reached!");
        }
      }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, ONE_DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS/*FIVE_SECONDS_IN_MILLISECONDS*/);
  }
}
```

Comment: These classes have been replaced by the [Executors framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). See the 7th paragraph on the JavaDoc for [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html).